# Want to use require multiple perl script

Tags: perl

Is it possible use require for more than one script?

eg

Main.pl

```
require "test1.pl"
require "test2.pl"

abc();
cde();
```

test1.pl

```
sub abc {
  print "I AM IN TEST1\n";
}
1;
```

test2.pl

```
sub cde {
   print "I AM IN TEST2\n";
}
1;
```

Comment: Well, what happens when you ... try it?

Comment: Come on, you've typed it all up. It would be quicker to push it through a perl interpreter and get your answer that way than to post it on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

yes.

note: make sure both `test1.pl` and `test2.pl` return true upon exiting or the script will fail. you will also want to add a semi-colon at the end of each `require` line in the `Main.pl` script.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can use as many `require`s as you want.

Answer (score 0):

> "Is it possible use require for more than one script?"

Yes. Make sure the requie'd scripts have this at the end:

```
1;
```

or you may get a *did not return a true value* error.

For more see the documentation about modules/packages:

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html